# Getting runtime error, C# Converting Array to Int

Tags: c#, arrays, runtime-error, valueconverter

for some reason this will compile but it comes out with an error at the end and I can't figure out why. The first part of the code is to display a table from a text file which works correctly, the second part doesn't.

I don't think it even gets to the Console.WriteLine bit, which was a way of checking whether it did. Can anyone see why?

Thanks for any help you can give!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        List<float> inputList = new List<float>();
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:/users/tom/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/DistanceCalculator3/DistanceCalculator3/TextFile1.txt");
        String input = Convert.ToString(tr.ReadToEnd());
        String[] items = input.Split(',');
        Console.WriteLine("Point         Latitude        Longtitude       Elevation");

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write((i / 3) + "\t\t");
            }

            Console.Write(items[i]);
            Console.Write("\t\t");

            if (((i - 2) % 3) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Ask for two bits of data which are then stored in Longtitude, Latitude and Elevation 

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the two points that you wish to know the distance between:");
        string point = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] pointInput = point.Split(' ');

        int pointNumber = Convert.ToInt16  (pointInput[0]);
        int pointNumber2 = Convert.ToInt16 (pointInput[1]);

        int Latitude = (Convert.ToInt16(items[pointNumber*3]));
        int Longtitude = (Convert.ToInt16(items[(pointNumber*3)+1]));
        int Elevation = (Convert.ToInt16(items[(pointNumber*3)+2]));

        int Latitude2 = (Convert.ToInt16(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));
        int Longtitude2 = (Convert.ToInt16(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));
        int Elevation2 = (Convert.ToInt16(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));

        Console.WriteLine("Latitude");
        Console.WriteLine("Latitude2");
```

Comment: Please include a stack trace.  Please also do this for all runtime errors you encounter in the future for any question.  Please also mark relevant line numbers.

Comment: debug your program and put break points where necessary

Comment: And since you're doing a bunch of `Console.Write`ing, it would help to also include this output *along with your expected output for a successful run*.

Comment: Show `TextFile1.txt`, else we don't know what you are parsing..

Comment: Ok, sorry guys I'm new to this. So the expected output for the Console.WriteLine at the bottom would be, if 0 and 1 were inputted by the user 1.2 and 7.8 would come out.

Comment: The textfile is 1.2,3.2,4.5,7.8,9.4,3.4,5.9,7.6

Comment: Your output can't be `1.2` and `7.8` because you're converting to an `int`. Integers are whole numbers, so you could use a float in this case.

Comment: I will try and upload an image of what coming out instead, its says line 50 at the end if that any help

Comment: By the way, your 3rd point in your file has no `Longtitude`specified...you should have 9 values instead of 8.

Comment: Ahh the float, thats probably it, even when i change all the ints to float and convert to single it underlines items[(pointNumber*3]) red

Comment: Yes i know the file is just to check its working different text is going to be added. My previous comment, its all of the items that are red when i try to use a float

Comment: Use `Convert.ToSingle` to convert to a float. (Also change `int Latitude` to `float Latitude` etc..)

Comment: Ah! I've got it working! Thanks guys!! Whoever mentioned the float is a hero, and the fact that there is no Longtitude specified was right!! <3 Heros!

Answer (score 1):

You are using decimal values, which cannot be converted into `Int16`. So use `float`.

Also, Outputting "Latitude" will write the variable's name, not its value.
I modified your code:

```
float Latitude = (float.Parse(items[pointNumber*3]));
float Longtitude = (float.Parse(items[(pointNumber*3)+1]));
float Elevation = (float.Parse(items[(pointNumber*3)+2]));

float Latitude2 = (float.Parse(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));
float Longtitude2 = (float.Parse(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));
float Elevation2 = (float.Parse(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));

Console.WriteLine(Latitude);
Console.WriteLine(Latitude2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input strings are of floating values, not integers. You can parse to floats like this:

```
float Latitude = (Convert.ToSingle(items[pointNumber * 3]));
float Longtitude = (Convert.ToSingle(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 1]));
float Elevation = (Convert.ToSingle(items[(pointNumber * 3) + 2]));

float Latitude2 = (Convert.ToSingle(items[pointNumber2 * 3]));
float Longtitude2 = (Convert.ToSingle(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 1]));
float Elevation2 = (Convert.ToSingle(items[(pointNumber2 * 3) + 2]));
```